# Problem with operator $in in aggregation-pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of users

```
[
  {
    roles: [
      "ADMIN",
      "USER"
    ]
  },
  {
    roles: [
      "ADMIN",
      "USER",
      "SUPER_ADMIN"
    ]
  },
  {
    roles: [
      "ADMIN"
    ]
  }
]
```

And I want to get in aggregation only user with roles `ADMIN` or 'SUPER_ADMIN'.

I use this aggregation, but this does not work.

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $in: [
          "$roles",
          [
            "USER",
            "SUPER_ADMIN"
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

What's wrong do I do?
Or Can I not use `$expr` in the pipeline of `$lookup`?

Version 4.0.21

example https://mongoplayground.net/p/RWoZaR3UY2U

Comment: Is [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5EvgkJrTGn0) what are you looking for?

Comment: I need this https://mongoplayground.net/p/2vUqe5UeEaD 
@J.F.

Comment: Check [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/). `$in` is `[ <expression>, <array expression> ]`. To return documents using you query you need a nested array (because you are using the array as first parameter). Check [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hk4Px2xJeCl)

Comment: I have already read the docs, but I haven't understood it. 
This example helps you to more understand what I want
https://mongoplayground.net/p/RWoZaR3UY2U

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/_pBOUWrMZC9 are you looking for this? Can you explain bit more

Answer (score 2):

I had got similar problem and after working for hours, I solved by making intersaction between document (database item) array and my filter array. If result is greater than 1, there match.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gt: [
          {
            $size: {
              $setIntersection: [
                "$roles",
                [
                  "ADMIN",
                  "SUPER_ADMIN"
                ]
              ]
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[image: mongodb playground]

This works for your problem as well.